# How to make a method generic in c#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have couple of methods and it keeps on expanding. So, I am planning to make it generic. Can anyone please help me with that. Atleast the method definition.

```
private static Dictionary<string, class1> PToDictionary(MapField<string, class1Proto> keyValuePairs)
{
    Dictionary<string, class1> keyValues = new();
    foreach (var pair in keyValuePairs)
    {
       **keyValues[pair.Key] = pToR(pair.Value);**
    }
    return keyValues;
}
```

My another method is :

```
private static Dictionary<Uri, class2> PToDictionary1(MapField<string, class2Proto> keyValuePairs)
{
        Dictionary<string, class2> keyValues = new();
        foreach (var pair in keyValuePairs)
        {
           **keyValues[new Uri(pair.Key)] = pToR1(pair.Value);**
        }
        return keyValues;
}
```

How can I make this generic so that when more methods are added, I dont need to add code.
I was thinking something like this, but errors are :

```
//   Not sure how to call this method after Func is there
    private static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> PToDictionary<TKey, TValue, TKeyProto, TValueProto>(MapField<TKeyProto, TValueProto> keyValuePairs, Func<TKeyProto, TKey> keyFunc, Func<TValueProto, TValue> valueFunc)
{
   //How can I generalize my above method ?
}
```

Can someone help me complete the method ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Have you [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) the documents? If not, it would be a great start. Also can you update your post to include a minimal example and expected output? Finally, `but it just gives error (red lines)` can you post these details? Where does `pToR` come from, what's its definition?

Comment: "but it just gives error (red lines) not sure how to solve." If you could show the complete example of what you tried to do, and what the exact errors are (rather more precisely than "red lines") then we'd be in a better position to help you.

Comment: What is the `MapField` class? Is it from `Google.Protobuf.Collections`?

Comment: @ruslan.gilmutdinov Yes, it is from `Google.Protobuf.collections`. And updated the method again.

Comment: "but errors are" - you still haven't told us what the error message is. You've shown a bit more code, but not quoted an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method to convert `MapField<TKeyProto, TValueProto>` to `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> PToDictionary<TKey, TValue, TKeyProto, TValueProto>(
    MapField<TKeyProto, TValueProto> keyValuePairs,
    Func<TKeyProto, TKey> mapKey,
    Func<TValueProto, TValue> mapValue
)
{
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> keyValues = new();
    foreach (var pair in keyValuePairs)
    {
        keyValues[mapKey(pair.Key)] = mapValue(pair.Value);
    }
    return keyValues;
}
```

Here, `mapKey` is a function that converts `MapField`'s key to a dictionary key. Similarly, `mapValue` converts `MapField`'s value to a dictionary value.

Another way is to make usage of LINQ [ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-todictionary-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-0-2)))) extension method:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> PToDictionary<TKey, TValue, TKeyProto, TValueProto>(
    MapField<TKeyProto, TValueProto> keyValuePairs,
    Func<TKeyProto, TKey> mapKey,
    Func<TValueProto, TValue> mapValue
)
{
    // this is possible because MapField<TKey, TValue> implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
    return keyValuePairs.ToDictionary(
        (KeyValuePair<TKeyProto, TValueProto> kvp) => mapKey(kvp.Key),
        (KeyValuePair<TKeyProto, TValueProto> kvp) => mapValue(kvp.Value));
}
```

For example, if you want to convert `MapField<string, string>` to `Dictionary<Uri, int>` you can use the following code:

```
Dictionary<Uri, int> dictionary = PToDictionary(
    map,
    key => new Uri(key),
    val => int.Parse(val));
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have couple of questions. I have a line like `keyValues[new Uri(pair.Key)] = pToR1(pair.Value)` and `keyValues[mapKey(pair.Key)] = mapValue(pair.Value)`. One time I need a Uri and other time a string, would this still work ?..And how can I call this function then. I use to just `PToDictionary(mapField object)`. What to pass in func ?

Comment: How to define Func ? When I call the method, at that time should I define a func ?

Comment: I am trying to call something like this but not sure what to do exactly. `PToDictionary(keyValuePairs, new Uri(), PToR)`. Like 1 func is to convert uri to string and vice versa and other func is to call PToR or PToR1.

Comment: To convert `MapField<string, class2Proto>` to `Dictionary<Uri, class2>` use: `PToDictionary(map, key => new Uri(key), val => pToR1(val))`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an extra method at all. LINQ already provides everything you need, combined with the fact that `MapField` implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` (and therefore `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

You'd just call:

```cs
var dictionary = repeatedField.ToDictionary(
    pair => ConvertKey(pair.Key), pair => ConvertValue(pair.Value));
```

(where `ConvertKey` would be whatever code you want to convert the repeated field key into the dictionary key, and likewise for `ConvertValue`).

Sample calls:

```cs
var d1 = repeatedField1.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pToR(pair.Value));

var d2 = repeatedField2.ToDictionary(
    pair => new Uri(pair.Key), pair => pToR1(pair.Value));
```

... but you may be able to remove the `pToR` and `pToR1` methods anyway. (It's hard to tell without information about what they're doing...)

Comment: Do I need to create a new method for ConvertKey and ConvertValue ?

Comment: And the method definition would be same ?

Comment: @meh: There *is* no method definition. And you *could* have a `ConvertKey` method, or you could just use a lambda expression. You were originally proposing a method accepting `Func<,>` methods, but it's not clear why you'd propose that if you don't know how you'd call it... What is `pToR` in your first example, for instance? If you could provide more complex examples of what you're trying to do, we could give you more concrete examples of how you'd implement that.

Comment: I am trying to call something like this but not sure what to do exactly. `PToDictionary(keyValuePairs, new Uri(), PToR)`. Like 1 func is to convert uri to string and vice versa and other func is to call PToR or PToR1.

Comment: @meh: I've added sample calls but they're not as useful as they would be with a more informative question. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for more detailed suggestions on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @meh: It sounds like really need to read up on "options for creating delegates in C#" (e.g. method group conversions, lambda expressions) which has nothing to do with declaring generic methods...